# JCIFS SmbFile RenameTo fails to a move file

Tags: java, groovy, smb

I have the strangest behavior using the JCIFS SmbFile.renameTo() method. When I execute the code below it should move the network file from test1 to test2, but instead it creates a folder in test2 called test.xml and throws the following error "Cannot create a file when that file already exists..." I can't figure it out. Why is this method doing this?

```
 NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication (sDomain, 
                                       sUsername, sPassword);
 SmbFile smbFromFile = new SmbFile("smb://test1/test.xml", auth);
 SmbFile smbToFile = new SmbFile("smb://test2/test.xml", auth);
 smbFromFile.renameTo(smbToFile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an interesting difference between [`copyTo(SmbFile)`](http://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#copyTo(jcifs.smb.SmbFile)) and [`renameTo(SmbFile)`](http://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#renameTo(jcifs.smb.SmbFile)) - only one of them says *This file and the destination file do not need to be on the same host.* As `renameTo(SmbFile)` does **not** say that, I can only assume you should use `copyTo` and then [`delete()`](http://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#delete()) the original.

```
SmbFile smbFromFile = new SmbFile("smb://test1/test.xml", auth);
SmbFile smbToFile = new SmbFile("smb://test2/test.xml", auth);
// smbFromFile.renameTo(smbToFile);
smbFromFile.copyTo(smbToFile);
smbFromFile.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible Scenarios:

1.) **The file needs to be moved on the same server** ( That is, the authentication details for Input folder and Output folder are same).

***Use renameTo() method.***

```
 public boolean moveFile(SmbFile file) {
    log.info("{"Started Archiving or Moving the file");
    String targetFilePath = this.archiveDir + file.getName(); //Path where we need to move that file.
    try {
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", userId, userPassword);
        log.info("targetFilePath: {} , currentFile : {}",targetFilePath, file);
        SmbFile targetFile = new SmbFile(targetFilePath, auth); 
          //authenticate the SmbFile
        try {
            file.renameTo(targetFile); //User renameTo method for same server
            log.info("Archived File : {} to: {}", file.getName(), 
            targetFile.getName());
            return true;
        } catch (SmbException e) {
            log.error("Unable to Archive File: {}", file.getName());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("Connection failed to Server Drive: {}", targetFilePath);
    }
    return false;
}
```

2.) **The file needs to be moved on Different server** ( That is, the authentication details for Input folder and Output folder are  ***NOT*** same).

***Use copyTo() method.***

Here I will suggest, You can firstly authenticate the first server on which file is present, And check if the File exists, If it is existing then add that in a list :

```
public List<SmbFile> xmlFiles = new ArrayList<>(); //Here we will add all the files which are existing.

public boolean isFileExists() throws MalformedURLException, SmbException {
  NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", 
  userID, userPassword); //authenticating input folder.
    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(inputFolder, auth);
    SmbFile[] smbFiles = smbFile.listFiles();
    boolean isFilePresent = false;
    if (smbFiles.length > 0) {
        for (SmbFile file : smbFiles) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)              
       .contains(AppConstant.FILE_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))) {
                xmlFiles.add(file);
                isFilePresent = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isPlanFilePresent) {
        log.info("Number of files present on Server: {}",smbFiles.length);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will give you the files in the list. Go ahead to copy it to another server. Note that you need to authenticate here for the output Folder only.

```
 public boolean moveFile(SmbFile file) {
    log.info("Started Moving or Archiving the file");
    String toFilePath = this.outputFolder + file.getName(); //path where you need to copy the file from input folder.
    try {
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", outputFolderUserId, outputFolderPassword); //authenticating output folder
        log.info("targetFilePath: {} and currentFile : {}", toFilePath, file);
        SmbFile targetFile = new SmbFile(toFilePath, auth1);
      
        try {
            file.copyTo(targetFile);
            file.delete(); //delete the file which we copied at our desired server
            log.info("Archived File : {} to: {}", file.getName(), targetFile.getName());
            return true;
        } catch (SmbException e) {
            log.error("Unable to Archive File: {}", file.getName());
            return false;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("Connection failed to Server Drive: {}", toFilePath);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Happy to Help :)